# Displaying the last tweet using twitter api and javascript only (client side)

Tags: javascript, twitter

I have a web page on which I want to display the last tweet of a specific username, say `my_username`, using javascript only (no server side programming). I looked up and found the easy way of doing this was:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://twitter.com/javascripts/blogger.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/my_username.json?callback=twitterCallback2&;count=1"></script>
```

But now it seems that this method is deprecated and is not working anymore. It gives the following error while running the script :

```
Blocked a frame with origin "https://platform.twitter.com" from accessing a frame with origin "null".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "https", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "file". Protocols must match.
```

Is there any method to do this on client side only. Can this be even done without using PHP/OAuth ? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks !

Comment: Why do you want to do this without PHP? Do you not have access to server-side code?

Comment: @SmokeyPHP No such issues. Its just that I am a front end guy developing the UI of the site. So I'm unsure whether i should get involved with back end right now or not.

Comment: No choice by the looks of it: see [this developer comment](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/10940#comment-23123) though that is ~50 weeks old... :/

Comment: @SmokeyPHP Hmmm... seems like I will have to do it with PHP only. Thanks !

Comment: You could look at [this workaround](http://jasonmayes.com/projects/twitterApi/) - though Twitter do strongly suggest using server-side